# How can I get the full error message returned from a linked server query?

Tags: t-sql, try-catch, linked-server

I've created a procedure on a MySQL server which will always throw an error due to a primary key violation, this would be called from a Microsoft SQL Server over a linked server using this:

`EXEC ('CALL temp_test;') AT LINKSVR;`

When this is called i get this full message:

```
OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "LINKSVR" returned message "[MySQL][ODBC 5.1 Driver][###########]Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'".
Msg 7215, Level 17, State 1, Line 1
Could not execute statement on remote server 'LINKSVR'.
```

Now what i want to do it put this in a `TRY...CATCH...`and output the error to a table, however when I use `ERROR_MESSAGE()` all I get us the last line

is there a way to get the linked server message that was returned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, got a good work around, it doesn't output to a table but i'm sure you can log it somewhere

effectively you do this

```
BEGIN TRY
    EXEC ('CALL sp_test;') AT LINKSVR;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    RAISERROR(N'Error called on Linked Server',16,1)
END CATCH
```

`RAISERROR` will output the custom error and the message returned from the Linked Server, however the message from the link server still can't be stored in a table but with the SQL Server Agent Job Activity Monitor the job will still fail at the step this occurs and in the step details all the data is outputted